# Are there any other Advaitic publishers in India restricted to Telugu language other than the follow?

Tags: scripture, book-recommendation, telugu

I know the following three publishers of Telugu books. They publish many scriptures that are highly useful and belongs to Advaithic interpretation of Sanathan dharma

1. [Gita Press Gorakpur](https://gitapressbookshop.in/index.php?route=product/category&path=75)
2. [Rama Krishna Math](https://www.vivekanandabookworld.com/product-category/telugu-books/)
3. [Sri Ramanamaharshi Ashram](https://bookstore.sriramanamaharshi.org/product-category/ebooks-telugu/)

I want to know whether there are any authentic publishers like above that publishes the books of Sanathan dharma in Telugu following *Advaita* sampradaya.

**Side note**: I am asking this question as the above publishers does not publish books like Hahta Yoga Pradipika, Gheranda Samhita, Ayurveda etc.,

Comment: You can search the Chaukhamba group of publishers & Khemraj Shrikrishnadas